# How do I validate data in C# based on a Struts validation.xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, struts, struts-validation

I have a `validation.xml` file from Struts, and am going to implement a server-side validation in .NET based on it. The `validation.xml` file is accompanied with a `validationMessages.properties` file. Are there any .NET libraries which are capable of performing a validation based on a Struts validation file?

In case this has never been done I'll have to either create such a class, since the validation file is too long and complex to be implemented as mere C# logic. Which begs the question: How would I even begin?

The end-goal is to be able to populate a C# class with properties for all fields, execute a validation method with that class as a parameter and have it return a list of validation error messages (or no errors in case of success).

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if anything like that existed; it's relatively unusual to move from Java -> .NET.

First, see if there are any custom validators. That code would need to be duplicated.

Then pick apart the different forms (or actions, depending on how they did validation). Put each of *those* into a C# class (but see below) rather than one giant one. I'm not sure what you mean by "A C# class with properties for all fields"; personally I'd go more granular.

Or just use an existing C# validation package and do a translator from Apache Commons Validation to the C# configuration (or code).

It should be a relatively straight-forward process since the validation config is well-known and documented, and all the code is available.